# Access object within an object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Hi everyone i am new to javascript. I want to use the property1 and its value from variable_name. When i output its value to console i get the 
structure below.

```
variable_name 
Object
variable_name1
:
{property1: "val1", property2: "val2", property3: "val3", …}
__proto__
:
Object
```

How do i access the property1 and it's value from the object mentioned above. I tried accessing variable_name.variable_name1.property1.val. It doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: use variable_name.variable_name1.property1

Comment: Objects are accessed using key names.

Comment: also it is object within object what if i have to get each object property1:val1

Comment: suppose its object within object and each object has property1,property2; how do i loop through each object to get property1 of each object. thanks